# How do I get post attachments in menu_order in Wordpress?

Tags: php, get-posts, menu-order

I'm struggling to get menu_order to work for images attached to a post. I am trying to pull all of the images attached to a specific post in the order specified via the drag-and-drop interface in the media window. Here is the code pulling the images:

```
$args = array(
    'post_type' => 'attachment',
    'post_mime_type' => 'image',
    'output' => 'ARRAY_N',
    'order' => 'ASC',
    'orderby' => 'menu_order',
    'post_parent' => $post_id /* This is defined elsewhere */
);
```

$images =& get_children($args);
This is not pulling the images in the order shown in when looking at the attached images in the media window of the post edit page. The order is instead ordered by date. Can anyone shed some light on this issue? I disabled the category order plugin I was using, and this did not remedy the problem.

EDIT:

Thanks to gdaniel for your help! I realized after following your advice and checking the image posts in my database that they all had a menu_order value of 0. I was able to temporarily fix this issue using the code in [this forum post](http://wordpress.org/support/topic/when-is-menu_order-set-for-attachments).

I'm looking for a way now to change the menu order on the event of drag and dropping images. Thanks to kaiser for his suggestions!

Comment: Check you wp_posts table in the database to see if the any of the attachments have a menu_order. I checked mine and they don't. It might be that it's not used in the same way as posts.

Comment: About double posts: Please delete one and rephrase the other one with an [edit] instead of a comment. And what you're trying to do will involve AJAX calls to save the data "on drop" - you'll want to research that one as well.